# RTP Audio Data integer type

Tags: c

In an application I am working on, I see code that looks something like this (paraphrasing).

```
size_t audio_length = 960;
uint32_t audio_data[audio_length];

size_t converted_length = audio_length * sizeof(uint32_t);
SendDataToApplication((char*)audio_data + sizeof(RtpHeader), converted_length);
```

They have some audio data in a `uint32_t` array including an RTP header. There's 4 `char`s packed into each `uint32_t` of audio data. They want to send the audio somewhere, so they cast to `char*` and skip the header.

Since they cast it to char, I assume this means that audio-carrying RTP packets would likely have audio data that is signed? ie from -127 to 127? Is audio data typically signed or unsigned? And where can I get more information about this, or would it be hardware specific?

Comment: The data type here doesn’t relate to the audio data. It’s usually compressed and very likely not 8bit anyway. Audio data can be anything. Also that code will probably cause undefined behavior due to going out of bounds unless sizeof RtpHeader is zero or the function subtracts from the length.

Comment: Yeah sorry it's from memory so it's probably not correct. Can you explain what you mean that it's likely not 8 bit anyway? And would you agree it could be signed data?

Comment: These days audio is usually not 8bit. It can be as well as any other amount of bits per sample. And it can be signed, or it can be unsigned. Either way goes but signed is the more common one. The datatype doesn’t reflect that here though.

Comment: Shouldn't `converted_length` have `sizeof(RtpHeader)` subtracted from it before being passed to `SendDataToApplication` ?

Comment: *Is audio data typically signed or unsigned* - that's an encoding issue. 8-bit WAV files on Windows are unsigned samples, whereas 16-bit WAV's are signed samples.

Comment: @selbie Yes, sorry. Just typed it up from memory. So how do you know that fact? Where can I learn this information, or do you just know from experience?